# C++ program to accept a string according to a particular rule (num opr num)

Tags: c++

I have a program that accepts particular string according to a defined rule, i.e., number operator number. For example:`2+4-5*9/8`

The above string is acceptable.
Now when I input something like `2+4-a`, it is again showing acceptable which is completely not acceptable as the number value should only range from 0 to 9 according to the rule defined. I think I will have to use ASCII values to check.

Refer to the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <curses.h>

int check(int stvalue) {
    if(stvalue < 9) return(1);
    else return(0);
}

main() {
    int flag = 0;
    char str[10];
    std::cout << "Enter the string:";
    std::cin >> str;
    int i = 1;
    int n = strlen(str);
    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i += 2) {
        if(!check(str[i])) {
            if(str[i + 1] == '+' || str[i + 1] == '-' || str[i + 1] == '/' || str[i + 1] == '*') flag = 1;
            else {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == 1) std::cout << "String is acceptable" << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "String is not acceptable\n" << std::endl;
    getch();
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 Enter the string:2+4-5
 String is acceptable

 Enter the string:3*5--8
 String is not acceptable

 Enter the string:3+5/a
 String is acceptable
```

The last output should not be acceptable.

Comment: You probably want `check(str[i] - '0')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i += 2) {
```

You don't check the last character of the string, so the final `a` gets through.

Remember `strlen` does not include the null char, you dont need to adjust for it.

Also use `check(str[i] - '0')` since you want to check on the number and not its ascii code.

Final big issue -

```
if(str[i] == '+' || str[i] ==
```

If check fails, **you need to check if that char is an operator**, **not the next one**, as above. [Output](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1uXtKy%2419)

Also set flag as 1 by default. I have [rewriten your code a little](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1uXtKy%2419).

[Further rewritten code which catches repeated digits or operators](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1uXtKy%2425)

Comment: It's showing acceptable even on input a-2+5 as well as on 2-a+5

Comment: @Bhavyanshu AH! If check fails, doesnt that mean the current char is non int, so has to be operator? why doing +1?

Comment: Your code definitely checks for alphabets but now it's not working on 4-5+4*7 which is an acceptable string.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working well now. Can you explain me a bit why there are "1"s in output?

Comment: @KarthikT: This fails for `1++++1`, it will return `true` when OP's rules say it should be `false`.

Comment: Oh nevermind..i got it..it's the flag value..couldn't see it in the code..I am getting blind. :P Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: I think i should use isdigit instead of check..! But your answer is pretty much close to what i want so it's acceptable. I will see what can be done for input like 1+++1. :)

Comment: @Bhavyanshu dreamlax's style is better to catch that issue, however you can do it [this way as well](http://liveworkspace.org/code/1uXtKy$25)

Answer (score 2):

```
int check(int stvalue) {
    if(stvalue < 9) return(1);
    else return(0);
}
```

This is wrong because the number equivalents on the ASCII chart are 48 to 57, going from 0 to 9.

You can probably simplify your validation by passing it through a function similar to this one:

```
#include <cctype>
bool validateString(const std::string& str) {
   auto compare = [](char c) {
        return ((c == '+') || (c == '-') || (c == '*') || (c == '/'));
    };
    size_t length = str.length();
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        if(!(std::isdigit(str[i]) || compare(str[i])))
            return false;
        if(compare(str[i]) && (i <= length-1) && compare(str[i+1]))
            return false;
        if(compare(str[length-1]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. That would validate `+++++` as `true` when clearly it breaks the required format.

Comment: @Rapptz Karthik's code is pretty much what i want but it also has the same problem as yours. Showing acceptable on ++++. I agree that check function is a wrong way of doing it. If you can just fix your code then it would be of great help. :)

Comment: @Bhavyanshu I have already fixed it and added a case if an operator is at the end, you can probably do the same for the front too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a few hints:

1. Your loop only checks an even amount of characters in your input. Your loop adds 2 to `n` each time, so it will check `3+` and `5/` but `a` will never get looked at.
2. If your input is always alternating between a single digit number and an operator, you can use something like the following:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // read *every* character
   {
       if (i % 2 == 0)
       {
           // you are looking at a character with an even index
       }
       else
       {
           // you are looking at a character with an odd index
       }
   }
   ```

   The `%` operator divides the left operand by the right and gives you the remainder of that division.
3. Your `check` function is checking whether the `char` value is less than 9, not whether the `char` value represents a digit character. You can include the `<cctype>` header and use `isdigit` instead of your `check` function, which checks to see if the input represents a digit character or not.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers are char type so check their ASCII value to see if they are numbers.

Answer (score 0):

ASCII value if 0 is 48 and 9 is 57.. not 9. So,
if(stvalue < 9) return(1);

should be,
if(stvalue <= 57) return(1);

By the way, this approach may work but other answers are more mature way of solving this problem.